# nginx configuration: How to allow a range of addresses?

Tags: nginx

How do I allow a range of IP addresses in nginx.conf?  For example I want to do something like this:

```
server {
    allow x.y.z.192 - x.y.z.255;
    deny all;

    <snip>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that you need to use [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) format, there's a lot of online converters

try this

```
allow x.y.z.192/26
```